# How can I use a shared error message Dialog in PrimeFaces

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

In PrimeFaces, when you want to show an error Message you can:

1. create in View a command Component that calls an action
2. in 'update' attribute, you set the id of the p:message or p:growl component that will display the message
3. in The backing Bean, in the action function you throw a message

As a result, the error message will be displayed in the redirect page, in the message component with the matching id

But what if :

1. You want to display the message in another page, that doesn't contain the command component that called the action.
2. The action can redirect to lots of different pages, depending on some Backing bean Logic.
3. The action is not called from a command Component, at least not directly

I've thought of putting a p:message component with a specific id, and include it in every xhtml page. But this would not necessarily cover the 3rd scenario.

For example, there could be a function that checks the connection to another Web Service. A Connection error could be thrown from lots of different Actions.

- Or a session expiration
- Or a denial of permission

How would you manage this kind of generic error messages ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could put the common `<p:dialog>` or `<h:message>` in a template file which is being used for all pages and give it a unique id. That way, it will be rendered for all the pages using that template.

This, is assuming that you're using templates that is.

**UPDATE**: If you wish to programmatically update the component, you can do so using [RequestContext#update()](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/api/3.5/org/primefaces/context/RequestContext.html#update%28java.lang.String%29)

For e.g.

```
if (someErrorCondition) {
    RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update("errorDialogId");
}
```

where `errorDialogId` is the ID of the common error dialog.

If you intend to use this approach, you need to remove the `update` atribute from your command component.

**See Also**

- [Calling Primefaces dialog box from Managed Bean function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19678210/1055089)

Comment: No templates, but I don't mind putting it in every page manually.

Comment: But this way, I'd have to put the common message's id in every command component's update, right ?

Comment: Yes, IDs will have to be passed for `update` attributes in your facelets.

Comment: Well, I Do mind adding that id in every facelet. Looks dirty to me. Any way around that ? e.g. setting the update attribute in Bean/Java side ?

Comment: Yes, you can update the component programmatically as well. See my edit.

Comment: You're welcome :) RequestContext is a VERY handy class. Do check its showcase page.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the `RequestContext#showMessageInDialog(FacesMessage)`?

As per their User Guide:

> Displaying FacesMessages in a Dialog is a common case where a
>   facesmessage needs to be added to the context first, dialog content
>   containing a message component needs to be updated and finally dialog
>   gets shown with client side api. DF (Dialog Framework) has a simple utility to bypass
>   this process by providing a shortcut;

Using this you don't need to have additional codes to put in every page you have. Just add it in your beans.