# Jsf InputText value Validation and Javascript Message

Tags: javascript, jsf, richfaces

I consider about a case in my JSF RichFaces application. I try to validate the Double type value in an input text. In the every keyup event, if the value is not proper, I would like to set the value in the inputtext to zero ( 0.0d ) and get a javascript alert. How can I accomplish it? My inputText code is below. Please note that I have already tried the JSF validators. But they produce JSF message, not javascript alert.

Thank you in advance.

```
    <h:inputText value="#{claimRefundOperation.amountPayable}"
                id="payableAmount" 
                disabled="#{claimRefundBean.allPartial=='All_COMPENSATION_AMOUNT'}">
        <a4j:ajax event="keyup" execute="@this" listener="#{claimRefundBean.onRefundOperationCheckBoxListener(claimRefundOperation)}"
                    onerror="return false;" render="totalAmount"/>
    </h:inputText>
```

Comment: Why do you want to use a 90's style JavaScript alert? It's an UX killer.

Comment: Instead, You can get dialogue from bean code. check below link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19678210/calling-primefaces-dialog-box-from-managed-bean-function