# primefaces commandbutton conditional statement

Tags: java, primefaces, conditional-statements, commandbutton

I want a conditional statement in my commandbutton (Primefaces 6.0) which should show a dialog if my java method return false or true. Something like that:

```html
<p:commandButton onclick="(myJavaMethod) ? deleteDialog.show() : confirmDialog.show()">
    <p:confirm header="Deleting Branch" message="Do you want to delete the Branch?"/>
</p:commandButton>
```

myJavaMethod return false if i can't delete it and true if i can delete it.

My Dialogs look like this:

```html
<!-- DELETE-DIALOG -->
<p:dialog id="deleteDialog" widgetVar="deleteDialog">
     <h:form id="deleteDialogForm">
        <h:panelGrid   columns="1" border="0">
        <p:outputLabel value="Branch could not be deleted"/>
            <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-close" id="doCloseDialog" oncomplete="PF('deleteDialog').hide()" value="OK" class="btn-confirm"/>
       </h:panelGrid>
    </h:form>
</p:dialog>
```

(Same Dialog with 'Edit' Dialog)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to do is to call a server side method with `onclick`, and you have to know that `onclick` 
is only a client side method, you can use it to call a javascript method and the javascript method will call a `p:remoteCommand` 
this is a simple example but i am pretty sure you can found more in other post to start about this topic read this post hope that will 
give more informations about it [How to call JSF backing bean method only when onclick event occurs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8705614/how-to-call-jsf-backing-bean-method-only-when-onclick-event-occurs) .

about your question you can use your method to conditionally call your dialog

Let see this example :

**ManagedBean.java**

```
public void myJavaMethod () {
...
if( condition ){
RequestContext context = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
context.execute("PF('myDialogVar').show();"); 
} else {
RequestContext context = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
context.execute("PF('myDialogVarOther').show();");      
}    
...    
}
```

and in your xhtml page it will look like this

**myXHTMLpage.xhtml**

```
 <p:commandButton actionListener="#{managedBean.myJavaMethod}">
 ...
 </p:commandButton>
```

you can read more in this post [Calling Primefaces dialog box from Managed Bean function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19678210/calling-primefaces-dialog-box-from-managed-bean-function).

Hope that helped you.