# How to get items of Primefaces picklist form transfer event in javascript

Tags: javascript, jsf, primefaces

As mentioned in [primefaces showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/pickList.xhtml) we can easily get the items from transfer event in the backing bean. However I need the items in my javascript function, as I need to add a css class after each item has been transfered to the target.

This is my xhtml:

```
 <p:pickList id="PojoPickList" value="#{pickListView.themes}" var="theme" effect="bounce"
                    itemValue="#{theme}" itemLabel="#{theme.displayName}" showSourceControls="true" showTargetControls="true" showCheckbox="true" responsive="true"
                    showSourceFilter="true" showTargetFilter="true" filterMatchMode="contains" converter="theme">    
    ...
      <p:ajax event="transfer" oncomplete="onTransfer(event);" />
    ...
```

and javascript function:

```
function onTransfer(event) {
    console.log(event);
}
```

But the event is undefined.Thanks.

Comment: change oncomplete with onclick and the event will be onclick

Comment: please read the answer that i give in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42107052/primefaces-commandbutton-conditional-statement/42107714#42107714) it will give you more informations to understand why it doesn't work

Comment: Thanks but onclick is not really what I need and I do not want to get any value from backing bean. There should be a way to get the items which will be transfered on client side.

Comment: What is it you want to accomplish, why do you need to add a class? Do all transferred items need to look different or what?

Comment: Yes, the transfered items are table columns. They should get an icon to show how they should be ordered, asc or desc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could solve the problem by overwriting the fireTransferEvent function in picklist.js of primeface. In this event, I have added the css classes, which I need. Now the items will get the css after transfering to the target list.