# Show Exception message in Primefaces

Tags: java, exception, jsf, primefaces, webclient

I have this Method that adds a new customer, So when i put a nickname that already exists an exception is thrown, how can i show the message of the exception in the adding form, iam using primefaces

```
   public String addCustomer() {

            webClient
            .post()
            .uri("/customer/addCustomer")
            .bodyValue(customer)
            .retrieve()
            .onStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST::equals,
                    response -> Mono.error(new NickNameExistException("NickName Exist. Please Try another one.")))
            .bodyToMono(Customer.class);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that you can show the message in a dialog like that (for more details see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19678210/calling-primefaces-dialog-box-from-managed-bean-function))

```
            webClient
            .post()
            .uri("/customer/addCustomer")
            .bodyValue(customer)
            .retrieve()
            .onStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST::equals,
                 response -> {
                 FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Error", "NickName Exist. Please Try another one");
                 // For PrimeFaces >= 6.2
                 PrimeFaces.dialog().showMessageDynamic(message);
             return Mono.error(new NickNameExistException("NickName Exist. Please Try another one."));
            }
            )
            .bodyToMono(Customer.class);
```